# html + js fade in fade out text comments

Tags: jquery, html, comments, fade

I have this code, which works pretty well, the only problem is after the last quote gets used it will show an empty div for a few seconds before starting from the beginning again. So, my question is how can I skip right back to the first quote after the last one is used. Thank you. (you can check it out in action at mapsbyphil dot com).

```
<div id="container">
<div>
 <p><b>"The early days of GIS were very lonely. No-one knew what it meant."</b><br><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Tomlinson"  target="_blank">Roger Tomlinson</a>, Father of GIS</p>
</div>
<div>
 <p><b>“GIS is a form of digital mapping technology.  Kind of like Google Earth, but better.”</b><br><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold_Schwarzenegger"  target="_blank">Arnold Schwarzenegger</a>, Conference on California's Future 2008</p>
</div>
<div>
 <p><b>“I am told there are people who do not care for maps, and I find it hard to believe.”</b><br><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Louis_Stevenson"  target="_blank">Robert Louis Stevenson</a></p>
</div>
<div>
 <p><b>“Everything is related to everything else, but near things are more related than distant things.”</b><br><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobler%27s_first_law_of_geography"  target="_blank">Tobler's First Law of Geography</a></p>
</div>
<div>
 <p><b>"It is not down in any map; true places never are."</b><br><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_melville"  target="_blank">Herman Melville</a></p>
</div>
<div>
 <p><b>"They were maps that lived, maps that one could study, frown over, and add to; maps, in short, that really meant something.” </b><br><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_Durrell"  target="_blank">Gerald Durrell</a></p>
</div>
<div>
 <p><b>“I get to go to overseas places, like Canada.” </b><br><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britney_Spears"  target="_blank">Britney Spears</a></p>
</div>
<div>
 <p><b>“I like geography. I like to know where places are.” </b><br><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Felton"  target="_blank">Tom Felton</a></p>
</div>
<div>
 <p><b>"I have no idea where Italy is on the map, but I do know what shape it is, and its like a boot." </b><br><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snooki"  target="_blank">Snooki</a></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function InOut(elem)
{
elem.delay()
 .fadeIn(600)
 .delay(5000)
 .fadeOut(600,
     function(){
        if(elem.next().length > 0) 
          { InOut(elem.next()); }
        else
          { InOut(elem.siblings(':first')); }

      }
    );
}

$('#container div').hide();
InOut($('#container div:first'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are actually trying to show the `<script>` as it is the last sibling. You may want to place the `<script>` outside the `<div id="container">`.

Or you can pass the selector `'div'` to the [`next()` function](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!  Just had to place an extra </div> right before the <script> and it works perfectly.  Thanks for your help.